# Download a file from a site (partly written in Javascript) using Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, download

I'm trying to use Python to download a voice file (mp3) from [this](http://ivona.com/pl/) site:

I've tried to use mechanize and twill but I haven't got the proper result. I've heard about selenium as well. Anyway, I don't even know if it makes sense technically (mechanize + Javascript).

I was looking for an answer and finally I've found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8289068/1126604).

It seems like a similar problem to mine but I have absoutely no idea what should I put instead of the 4th line.

If you have any proposition (maybe completely different to mine) I'll be glad to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Moving to answer to get more space)*

Thanks for pointing me to selenium, I didn't know that and it looks cool; anyways: I had a quick look and the js seems to fire an ajax request, that yields no apparent result -- I guess the audio transfer is done some way in the background via flash or so; anyways: what about using the service they offer: developer.ivona.com instead of trying hacking your webservice out of the demo interface..?

Anyways, here it is the hacked web-service you asked for:

This is the URL you want to GET:

```
"http://www.ivona.com/voicetest.php?rtr=1&t2r=%(the_text)s..&v2r=dXNfc2FsbGk.&lang=us" % dict(
    the_text=base64.b64encode("Hello, world!"),
    the_voice=base64.b64encode("us_salli"),
    )
```

You can test that with, for example, mplayer:

```
mplayer "http://www.ivona.com/voicetest.php?rtr=1&t2r=SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==..&v2r=dXNfc2FsbGk.&lang=us"
```

And, from Python, use urllib to retrieve and store somewhere.

Beware that, since this is an unauthorized use, you might get blocked / incur in legal issues / etc. -- don't use in a production application!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. There's a (little) problem anyway. It works great when it comes to English but if I put for example "pl_jacek" instead of "us_salli" and change "Hello, world!" to a Polish word it doesn't work properly (still English pronunciation) ;( I think it depends on the URL, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm not really sure on which the names for languages should be, anyways if you have a look with the Firebug console, you'll see POST requests generating when you click the PLAY button: the value of the `v2r` argument is the one you have to use. Also, change `&lang=us` to `&lang=pl`

Comment: Now it works perfectly! I'm really grateful. You saved my time and I've learned something new additionally. Bow down.

Comment: First thing while doing stuff like this, always have a look at the undergoing traffic! -- by using Firebug, HttpFox and Wireshark

Comment: Ok, I will. I didn't think indeed. Well, maybe because I'm a beginner in this matter. I just wanted something faster and more reliable than automated high-level tools (Sikuli, class Robot in Java etc.) and your solution seems like the best for me so thanks again.