# Download zip file from web page with javascript href

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, hyperlink, download

I want to create a python script for downloading the zip file from the following web site:

https://www.histdata.com/download-free-forex-historical-data/?/ascii/1-minute-bar-quotes/eurusd/2018

I can see the link to the zip file. If I click on it the zip file download starts.

I see that the code for that file in the page is the following one:

```
<a title="Download the zip data file" id="a_file" href="javascript:return true;" target="nullDisplay">HISTDATA_COM_ASCII_EURUSD_M1_2018.zip</a>
```

So I don't have directly a link that I can get in order to download the file.

In order to get the list of links I've used the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests
import re

pageLink = "https://www.histdata.com/download-free-forex-historical-data/?/ascii/1-minute-bar-quotes/eurusd/2018"
data = requests.get(pageLink)
dataSoup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, features="html.parser")
linkPattern = re.compile(r".*\.zip.*")
for dataLink in dataSoup.find_all('a'):
  print("--- Downloading zip file: " + dataLink.get('href'))
```

With this I obtain all the links of the page, but the zip one does not appear. If I replace `dataSoup.find_all('a')` with `dataSoup.find_all('a', href=linkPattern)` The list is empty.

How I can download the zip file from the script?

EDIT:

I've seen the other question that should be this duplicate, but I cannot find a way to make it work.

From the link I can see that the script should be `"javascript:return true;"`, so I've created the following code:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import re

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()

```
pageLink = "https://www.histdata.com/download-free-forex-historical-data/?/ascii/1-minute-bar-quotes/eurusd/2018"
browser.get(pageLink)
browser.execute_script("javascript:return true;")
```

Even in this case it doesn't work, so I cannot find a solution also by locking the duplicated question.

EDIT2:

I've seen that the javascript doesn't anything. The fact seems that the link has a target `nullDisplay`. When I click the link it seems that the target is called, that's the following code:

```
<form id="file_status" name="file_status" target="nullDisplay" method="POST" action="/getStatus.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="tk" id="tk" value="632ec105a874a64a1cf28120afa145e5" />
        <input type="hidden" name="date" id="date" value="2019" />
           <input type="hidden" name="datemonth" id="datemonth" value="201910" />
        <input type="hidden" name="platform" id="platform" value="ASCII" />
        <input type="hidden" name="timeframe" id="timeframe" value="M1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="fxpair" id="fxpair" value="EURUSD" />
    </form>

So the problem is how to recognize this post and how to use it for downloading data.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Get download link from javascript button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288202/python-get-download-link-from-javascript-button) - for you it's not a button, but this question is still a duplicate.